# Updating AWS Lambda with New Zip File?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I've created an AWS Lambda using a the AWS CLI. I did this by running the command:

```
aws lambda create-function
```

with the argument

```
--zip-file fileb://file-path/zipFile.zip
```

So then I want to make a change to the source code, so I made a new zip file but the lambda still executes with the old zip file's source code. Thus I tried to run the same command again but got the following error:

```
Function already exist: FunctionName
```

So either I just have to abandon that function and create a new one with the new zip file or there's some way for me to update the existing function to use the new zip file's code.

Is there a way for me to do this update, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create-function`, as the name implies, creates functions. It does not update them with new code. For that you need [`update-function-code`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html). This also takes a `--zip-file` argument.

While this updates the code, you may also need to publish a new version of the function for the changes to take effect. This can be done by adding the `--publish` argument to `update-function-code`, or as a separate step with the [`publish-version`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/publish-version.html) command.

Comment: For someone like me. Make sure you are using: `update-function-code` not `update-function-configuration`.